# Creating a Git directory inside the mnt folder

Tags: git, ubuntu, vmware

I am using VMWare (Ubuntu) on my Windows machine. I share folders between the operating systems using the `/mnt` directory.

When I try to use "git init ." inside the `/mnt` directory through the VM I get an error msg:

> Segmentation fault

Is there anyway I can create a git directory within the `/mnt` directory?

Comment: `/mnt` is a special folder -- why do you want to create a git repository in there?

Comment: Since I am editing the files in Windows (where I have most of my programs installed), but I want to run a Django project on Ubuntu. So I use the /mnt folder to share the files from Windows to Ubuntu

Comment: You should be creating a git repository inside the folder(s) that you are sharing via `/mnt`, not in `/mnt` itself.

Most likely the reason you can't `git init` inside `/mnt` is that you don't have write permissions on this folder.

Comment: For me, `git init` in `/mnt` gave an error “Permission denied”. `sudo git init` worked (I am not saying you should do this, though).

Comment: @Chaitanya Gupta - I am trying to create a git repository inside a directory of /mnt, not /mnt itself...

Comment: Ok. So do you have write permissions for those directories?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a known bug: http://blog.breadncup.com/2011/02/26/vmware-tool-patch-for-linux-kernel-2-6-3738/

I dig for the resolution, also.